# ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt installed, still recording functionality is not working

Tags: jmeter

I have imported the certificate - *ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt*

but still I am getting the below message and it doesn't record.
Please suggest.

Steps I followed:

Under *Workbench*, I have added a '`HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder`' > then a `'Sample Controller'`.

I am clicking the Start button in the *'HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder'* to start recording.
I have set the Port to *8080* and same I have set in my IE web browser.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure to setup correctly recording use Recording Template.

[image]

[image]

Then configure your browser to point to the proxy host / ports

Check it's ok by calling a page in browser BEFORE STARTING RECORDER, if you get proxy error then it's OK if you get the page, fix your proxy settings in Browser.

Start Browser

Call Https Page and accept exception

Read this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP%28S%29_Test_Script_Recorder